# Laravel 5 - upload file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, file-upload

I have this HTML form:

```
<form action="{{ route('send_form') }}" method="post" class="send_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" class='token' value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
        <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="" >
        <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" />
        <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

I'm tring to upload the file via ajax in this why:

```
$(".send_form").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);

    var $form = $( this),
        url = $form.attr( "action");

    $.ajax({
        url: url,  //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$form.find('.token').val() },
        // Form data
        data: new FormData($form[0]),
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        //Ajax events
        success: function( data ) {
            conosle.log('yesss');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

I can see that the file sent via the Request payload in the Chrome dev tools:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryBXAYgtRKJjEyH6NP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="01.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

In my Laravel controller, I can't get the input in any why. The `Input::all()` return empty, the `Request::instance()->all()` is empty, also `Input::get('fullname')` is empty.

At the start of my controller code I have all this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Request;
use Response;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Lang;
use Validator;
use Input;
```

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: You're asking what you can do? You can ask yourself why you try to get a file via the regular input method. In plain PHP is the file also a special kind of input which has it's own array (`$_FILES`) and that's not different in Laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files

Comment: when I do print_r($_POST); print_r($_FILES); it's also shows two empty arrays. As I said, the problem is not only in the file, also the input field gets empty

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file is actually uploaded (see below), you don't access it like a normal input. There is a special method for accessing files called `file`. So `\Request::instance()->file('myfile')` is what you want.

Be careful when doing AJAX file uploads without a third party fallback like Blueimp. It looks like most modern browsers support it now, but IE 8 and 9 do not and IE 10 and 11 do not support `responseType: 'json'`. Support on mobile (Android 4.4 and below, Opera Mini) is limited as well. ([Source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) + some fun past bug fixing)

Comment: As I said, the problem is not only in the file, also the input field gets empty